# Project naming conventions: [Company].[ProjectName] vs [Company_ProjectName]

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, projects-and-solutions

Is it good practice to name preface project names within a solution like so?

- CompanyName.P01
- CompanyName.P02
- CompanyName.P03

Or is it safer to use a convention like this?

- CompanyName_P01
- CompanyName_P02
- CompanyName_P03

To me, the [.] separator looks nicer, and provides intellisense, but is there any caveat to using it?

Comment: That's what namespaces are for.

Comment: Yes, but is it a good idea across separate projects?

Comment: In other words, using the character '.' in the project name

Comment: I don't think it makes much difference.  The idea that you are prefacing each of your projects with Company Name seems to make for a lot of extra verbage.  Why don't you name the solution Company Name and each project Project Name?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to avoid potential namespace conflicts, and it would provide the added benefit of allowing modules from the company code-base to be accessed through intellisense by simply typing "using CompanyName."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most of the solutions I came across follow the following convention:

```
CompanyName.SolutionName.LayerName
```

So basically in a company named `COMP` and a Project Named `StackOverflow`, you would end up with a project that looks like this:

```
COMP.StackOverflow.Business
COMP.StackOverflow.Data
COMP.StackOverflow.Web
COMP.StackOverflow.Core
```

This allows you to easily manage the generated assembly, so if you need to create a common library to be used in your company. You would name it:

```
COMP.SomeFrameworkName;
```

That would easily seperate your company's (or Team's) Dlls from external Dlls and Nuget Packages.

Comment: Can you add a description of the usage of those names?  I assume Business includes logic and rules, what I call "domain" code, and some call the "BLL".  Data being the common "DAL", or an ORM implementation, Web may be an API, but might also simply be the Website, and Core is... what I would call the Contracts, the Interfaces, Abstractions, Models, and maybe some super basic implementations.  In my mind the Business NuGet consumes the Core NuGet.  Can you please check your thoughts against mine and add what you thought when listing these conventions?